# div absolute positioning not working in different window size or resolution

Tags: html, css

Please refer below fiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/LHZDh/2/

code :

```
<body>

    <div style="position: relative; left: -5px; top: 18px;"><img id="ImgTachoMetre" src="/Images/u174_normal.png"/></div>


<div class="report_area" style="width: 1011px;">





<table class="NNACorporateSectiontop">
    <tbody><tr>

        <td>
            <div class="ActionItems_wrapper row0 box bordered span4 dbBG">
                <span class="title" style="background-color: #C71444; background-image:none; color:White;"><strong>Action Items</strong></span>
                <div class="component-body">



    <div class="HotAlertRoot">


        <table class="HotAlerts" align="center">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Total Open
                </td>
                <td>


                    <a class="redirectLink" href="/?Length=0">177</a>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Recent: 0 - 3 Days
                </td>
                <td class="NNABoldText">
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Serious: 4 - 7 Days
                </td>
                <td class="NNABoldText">
                    0
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Critical: &gt; 7 Days
                </td>
                <td class="NNABoldText">
                    177
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody></table>

        <table class="HotAlertsDept">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Sales
                </td>
                <td>
                    Service
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>Total Open 

                </td>
                <td>



                    <a href="/">65</a>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <a href="/">112</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

        <div class="GreyArea"></div>


        <div class="CorpPerformance Alert">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="CvalPending">
                    Pending


                    <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="All" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                </div>
                <div>
                    &lt;5 Days to Edit Email

                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="All" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table class="HotAlertsDept">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    Sales
                </td>
                <td>
                    Service
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td>Total

                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="Sales" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                </td>
                <td>

                    <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="Service" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>


    </tr>
</tbody></table>

</div>
    </body>
```

i need to place the icon in top corner of actionitems section. please refer below expected image.

[image]

but it's out of alignment in some resolution or window size changes.

misaligned screenshot:

[image]

how can i fix this ?

Comment: You're going to need to update your fiddle: at the moment the images don't work!

Comment: @john that's dummay image. could you please try with dummay image and place this correct in position for all window sizes

Answer (score 0):

Use "margin" instead of "left" and "top".

http://fiddle.jshell.net/LHZDh/2/

Code:

```
<body>

    <div style="position: relative; margin: 18px 0 0 -5px; ">
        <img id="ImgTachoMetre" src="/Images/u174_normal.png"/>
    </div>


    <div class="report_area" style="width: 1011px;">





        <table class="NNACorporateSectiontop">
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        <div class="ActionItems_wrapper row0 box bordered span4 dbBG">
                            <span class="title" style="background-color: #C71444; background-image:none; color:White;">
                                <strong>Action Items</strong>
                            </span>
                            <div class="component-body">



                                <div class="HotAlertRoot">


                                    <table class="HotAlerts" align="center">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Total Open
                                                </td>
                                                <td>


                                                    <a class="redirectLink" href="/?Length=0">177</a>
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                    Recent: 0 - 3 Days
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="NNABoldText">
                    0
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                    Serious: 4 - 7 Days
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="NNABoldText">
                    0
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                    Critical: &gt; 7 Days
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="NNABoldText">
                    177
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                    <table class="HotAlertsDept">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td/>
                                                <td>
                    Sales
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                    Service
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td>Total Open 

                                                </td>
                                                <td>



                                                    <a href="/">65</a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>

                                                    <a href="/">112</a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                    <div class="GreyArea"/>


                                    <div class="CorpPerformance Alert">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="CvalPending">
                    Pending


                                                <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="All" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                    &lt;5 Days to Edit Email

                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="All" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <table class="HotAlertsDept">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td/>
                                                <td>
                    Sales
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                    Service
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td>Total

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="Sales" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                                                </td>
                                                <td>

                                                    <a class="redirectLink" data-criteria-awaitingemailupdate="1" data-criteria-department="Service" data-criteria-reportperiod="[Collection Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Month].&amp;[February 2014]" data-criteria-summaryperiod="3MONTH" href="/Corporate/Disposition">0</a>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>


                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

If you wanna don't affect "Action Items" position, use "position:absolute" for parrent div.

Comment: how it will work all cases ? for me need to work in all window sizes and screen resolutions ?

Comment: You should know your "#ImgTachoMetre" sizes, and find their nagative and half values. For example your image size 200x400 (widthxheight),   and your left/top values will be; left=width/2=100px, top=height/2=200px. Finally add margin; like this: "margin: 200px 0 0 100px"

Answer (score 0):

Add two `<div>`'s like this, and remove this `/>`:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div style="position: relative; left: -5px; top: 18px;"><img id="ImgTachoMetre" src="/Images/u174_normal.png"></div>


<div class="report_area" style="width: 1011px;">

</div>
```

Comment: i can't get your answer? could you please more specific

Comment: You need to put your picture and report_area in a container.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position `#ImgTachoMetre` relative to `.ActionItems_wrapper` then you probably should have put it inside it, or at least before or after it so they have the same parent and they can both be positioned relative to the same element.
Try both and see what fits you most. This is not a rule of course, but it is a good practice.

Comment: Thanks .could you please modify my fiddle accroding to your solution?

Comment: @SivaRajini even if I did, the fiddle looks so broken that it won't make any difference, experiment a little on your local version.